# NSComboBox has no large controlSize?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I wanted to move my UI to the new large `controlSize` in macOS 11, so I set all controls to the "Large" size in the interface builder size inspector under:

```
Size Inspector > Control > Size > "Large"
```

However I can't get an `NSComboBox` to display in a large control size. The irony is that it is basically a mix of `NSTextField` and `NSPopUpButton`, which both have a proper large size (the combo box is the one on the bottom).

[image]

Seems like a major oversight, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width, but the height is fixed by the system.

```
NSComboBox ControlSize： 
large/regular height = 25;
small height = 22;
mini height = 22;
```